# How to provide custom parameters for triggered email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, soap-api, email-template, java

I'm going to use SOAP API via Java and plan to send triggered emails. How to provide custom parameters during email send invocation?

Example to explain my usecase: I generate some secret key in my standalone application and I want to put it into email for user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page in the documentation covers it: [Triggered Email Scenario Guide For Developers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/triggered_email_scenario_guide_for_developers.htm)

Here's a sample SOAP envelope that shows the structure of the attributes:

```
<exacttarget>
    <authorization>
        <username>apiuser</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </authorization>
    <system>
        <system_name>triggeredsend</system_name>
        <action>add</action>
        <TriggeredSend xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns='http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI'>
            <TriggeredSendDefinition>
                <CustomerKey>WelcomeEmail</CustomerKey>
            </TriggeredSendDefinition>
            <Subscribers>
                <SubscriberKey>jcruz@example.com</SubscriberKey>
                <EmailAddress>jcruz@example.com</EmailAddress>
                <Attributes>
                    <Name>FirstName</Name>
                    <Value>John</Value>
                </Attributes>
            </Subscribers>
        </TriggeredSend>
    </system>
</exacttarget>
```

Comment: do I understand correctly that triggered send named "WelcomeEmail" with mapped email template should already exists in system? and this email template should contain placeholder %%FirstName%%?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  The Customer/External Key for the Triggered Send Definition configured in the account needs to match the CustomerKey specified in the API call.

Comment: You can reference the Attributes as you've suggested.

Comment: thank you, I hope it works as long as I don't have an access to Marketing Cloud  to verify :)